# Ruby array of objects subtraction by object value

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays which contain objects of assets, now I want to subtract to get only objects from the first array which the second array doesn't have. I should use "-" right?

Here is my object

```
class Asset
  attr_accessor :id, :url, :text, :img_url, :type, :created_at

  def initialize(url, text, type, img_url, created_at)
    @id, @url, @text, @img_url, @type, @created_at = "", url, text, img_url, type, created_at
  end

  def eql?(another_asset)
    self_domain = UrlUtils::get_domain(self.url)
    another_asset_domain = UrlUtils::get_domain(another_asset.url)
    if self_domain == 'youtube' && another_asset_domain == 'youtube'
      self_youtube_id = UrlUtils::get_parameter(self.url, "v")
      another_asset_youtube_id = UrlUtils::get_parameter(another_asset.url, "v")
      return self_youtube_id.eql?(another_asset_youtube_id)
    end
    return self.url.eql?(another_asset.url)
  end

  def hash
      @created_at.hash + 32 * @url.hash
  end
end
```

The idea is one asset can contain url from youtube which every url might be different but it's the same video, so I have to compare each url with parameter "v" (youtube_id).

And this is my test which is wrong at the moment, because it doesn't do the subtraction correctly.

```
it "should substract duplicated youtube from mixed assets" do
    mixed_assets = Array.new
    all_assets = Array.new

    google = Asset.new("http://www.google.com", "", "", "", Time.now)
    youtube = Asset.new("http://www.youtube.com?v=1", "", "", "", Time.now)
    mixed_assets.push(google)
    mixed_assets.push(youtube)

    another_youtube = Asset.new("http://www.youtube.com?v=1&a=1", "", "", "", Time.now)
    all_assets.push(another_youtube)

    mixed_assets = mixed_assets - all_assets
    mixed_assets.length.should eql 1
    mixed_assets[0].url.should eql "http://www.google.com"

  end
```

I'm very new to ruby and I did some research that I should implement "hash" method as well, but I couldn't find any example how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work, the test should just return one array which it should be google asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array subtraction works via hashes, so you're correct. I couldn't test since I don't know what `UrlUtils` is, but something similar to the following is likely what you need added to the `Asset` class:

```
def hash
  domain = UrlUtils::get_domain(self.url)
  v = domain == 'youtube' ? UrlUtils::get_parameter(self.url, "v") : ''
  domain.hash ^ v.hash
end
```

You might also need an `eql?` method. There's a bunch of additional information in [this post](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/018-Complete_Class.html) that you probably will want to look over; it covers this, as well as a bunch of related topics.

Comment: @toy No problem. I updated it a bit; it wasn't quite right (it still may not be, but it's closer :)